# No Column formating template

Tags: template, list-template, formatting, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to add a column format template , basically marking the column “red” when the column is set to “No”  and “blue” for when it is “Yes”.

My custom columns, they don’t have the option  to select a template. I can only paste a JSON code. The first picture shows that.

I am quite sure it was working perfectly fine with my custom columns a couple weeks ago:

[image]

The second one shows how it should look or what I actually want:

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of your column?

Comment: The type of information in  column is: Choice (use it because  I use Require that this column contains information:   )

Comment: Is it showing same for all choice columns? In all lists? or some particular columns?

Comment: I added a SharePoint choice column  and the option is there but why is it not showing with my custom created column

Comment: I am not getting you. How you have created custom column?

Comment: As a way to help other thatm ight face the same problem I answered my own questions, after I figured it out what cuased the problem. You can test and please mark it as answered if you think it should be. thank u

Comment: Great, You can mark it as an answer on you own.

Comment: Apparently, I have to wait two day to accept my own answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to  answer my own question. After me playing around with settings of the column I figured it out
In case your column settings for display the choice is set to Drop-Down Menu, then everything will work fine, and you will get the format column template.

[image]

In case your column settings for display the choice is set to Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)  then you won't see the  format column template.

[image]